# Create one class to perform all type orm functionalities

Tags: typescript

I'm trying to create a separate package in a monorepo to handle `TypeORM` functions. So if I have two APIs (User API, Admin API), both can refer to the same package to talk to the database. I have written a class which takes all the TypeORM entities, create a connection and export them. Please let me know whether I can further refactor this:

```
import { createConnection, Connection, Repository, getConnectionOptions } from 'typeorm';
import { User } from './entity/User';

class Store {
  private dbConnection: Connection | undefined;

  private userRepository: Repository<User> | undefined;

  /**
   * Create a new DB connection and set repositories
   */
  createDBConnection = async (): Promise<void> => {
    const connectionOptions = await getConnectionOptions();

    this.dbConnection = await createConnection({
      ...connectionOptions,
      entities: [User],
    });

    this.userRepository = await this.dbConnection.getRepository(User);
  };

  /**
   * Throw an error if the repository is not available
   */
  private connectionNotCreatedError = (): never => {
    throw new Error('Repository not available. Please check whether you created the connection first.');
  };

  /**
   * Get the user repository
   */
  getUserRepository = (): Repository<User> => {
    return this.userRepository || this.connectionNotCreatedError();
  };
}

export const store = new Store();
```

Comment: IMHO, it makes no sense. You should obtain the repository asynchronously.

Comment: @slepic Didn't get you. I created this part will be replicated in both the repos. Trying to take it into one place.

Comment: I mean why not just have `async getUserRepository(): Promise<Repository<User>>`? You can even implement it in a way that it is only loaded once and on consecutive calls, the already fulfilled promise is returned.

Comment: @slepic Awesome so that means it remembers the result and won't call the function all the time? Do we have to implement it in a special way for that to work?

Comment: Ah sry, I missed that. I'm not really working with typescript daily, so I'm not sure how to do it from scratch. But I'm pretty sure it is possible...